# C# DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled in Windows 10 machine

Tags: c#, winforms

C# application.exe not working in Win10,but it worked on my Win7. I tried to debug in Win10 it shows me this error which is correct in win7.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string fullComputerName = Environment.MachineName;

        //Create a Folder Path
        string createFolderPath = @"C:\\Users\\" +fullComputerName+"\\Documents\\Cheques";

        //Create a File Inside of a Folder
        string createTxtFile= createFolderPath + "\\ChequeForDeposit.TXT";

        try
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(createFolderPath))
            { return; }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(createFolderPath);
        }
        catch { }
        finally { }

        if(!File.Exists(createTxtFile))
        { File.Create(createTxtFile); }//The error is here
    }
}
}
```

when i check in my win7 pc, it creates a folder and a text file. But not in Win10. it is so strange.

Comment: what is the error, in the catch statement, i thk access is denied!

Comment: it doesnt create the folder & file in win10.

Comment: catch(Exception e) { }, get this exception and see what it is, is it access denied?

Comment: exception e "the variable e is declared but never used. it is not an access is denied

Comment: ok try to create the directory as mentioned in my comment below, give the same path as mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try/catch does not ensure that directory folder will exist (may generate an exception when you try to create the folder). So before creating the file, check immediately folder is exists.
Your condition is incorrect. If folder not exists then you should return, otherwise create.

```
 try
 {
  if(Directory.Exists(createFolderPath) && !File.Exists(createTxtFile))
    { 
       File.Create(createTxtFile);   
    }
}
```

Also check the permission issue. e.g. Check the permissions for the desktop folder. In Windows Explorer right click on the desktop folder, select properties and there go to the security tab. You should have write permission for that folder.

Comment: i changed my code as you proposed and it worked fine without any errors. but when i checked at the directory in my local c, the createpathdirectory is actually not created. i cant see the folder and file that i created. i test both win7 & win10. win10 is not created this path

Comment: check the permission issue. can you try in another directory? e.g D:\NewFolder\FileName.txt

Comment: i've tried in C:\\NewFolder but it still didnt worked, i dont have a D directory in my both computer. How to changed the permission issue?

Comment: try this path. It's your desktop path.
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`

Comment: yes it created a textfile. then i tried to create a folder in the desktop(it failed). it is so strange with this win10. i think it is a bug, i tried to change the permission to fullcontrol but still the same.

Comment: Also check the permission issue. e.g. Check the permissions for the desktop folder. In Windows Explorer right click on the desktop folder, select properties and there go to the security tab. You should have write permission for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

i think the folder C:\Users\ is **Protected system folder** by design. either you have to run as Administrator or **create the file in some other drive**, for eg:

```
@"D:\Users\" +fullComputerName+"\Documents\Cheques"
```